# What book could this character have come from?

Tags: character-development, pages-and-co

In Anna James' [*Pages & Co: Tilly and the Bookwanderers*](https://www.harpercollins.co.uk/9780008229863/pages-and-co-tilly-and-the-bookwanderers-pages-and-co-book-1/), we learn that the character

> Enoch Chalk

is actually a fictional character who has

> escaped from the Source Library edition of his book.

This apparently escapes notice for a long time because

> Hardly anyone reads Enoch's book.

The other fictional characters that we see

> visiting the real world

are famous ones that the reader is expected to recognize, such as Alice in Wonderland and Anne of Green Gables. This makes it odd that

> we don't find out what book Enoch is from, other than that it is very obscure.

Although we aren't explicitly told the name of this character's book, are there any hints as to what it might be or what author might have created him?

Answer (score 2):

It could be a reference to the [Book of Enoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch)

> The Book of Enoch is an ancient Hebrew apocalyptic religious text, ascribed by tradition to Enoch, the great-grandfather of Noah. Enoch contains unique material on the origins of demons and giants, why some angels fell from heaven, an explanation of why the Great Flood was morally necessary, and prophetic exposition of the thousand-year reign of the Messiah.

It fits the description, in that, while it is an ancient Hebrew text, it is not considered canonical by most Christians or religious Jews, therefore it's not well read or known.